# Writing a 2D vector to a file? c++

Tags: c++, file-io, dictionary, vector, sfml

I'm wondering how I can output a 2D vector to a file with spaces in between the values. It's to write a map to a file at a specified size that the user chooses. I am already dynamically loading the map from there. I have a basis for the function but I'm kind of lost on the next bit.

```
void Map::SetMapSize(int sizeX, int sizeY, const char *filename)
{
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    out << "[Map]" << std::endl;
    MapSizeVector[sizeX][sizeY];

    for(int i = 0; i <= sizeX; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= sizeY; j++)
        {
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(out, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The Map.txt looks like this:

```
[Map]
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It also has a details bit underneath it. Basically, I want to rewrite that [Map] part to whatever size x and y the user requests above the [Details] and replacing the existing [Map] part. The numbers are fine with being 0. Thanks!

Declaration of vector in Map.h

```
std::vector <std::vector <int> > MapSizeVector;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `out << MapSizeVector[i][j];` instead of `MapSizeVector[sizeX][sizeY];`?

Comment: If I do that I get vector subscript out of range and it deletes everything in the Map.txt and then only prints [Map]

Comment: There I was just setting the size of the vector.

Comment: OK, but you do that (sizeX + 1) * sizeY times. It's meaningless. You should initialize the map once before the loops and then print a single value in the for loop.

Comment: Yep thanks. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Edited OP with new function

Comment: Could you post the declaration of `MapSizeVector`? Is this a type or what?

Comment: Yeah it's of type integer. I added the declaration to the OP.

Comment: @user1816388 `MapSizeVector[sizeX][sizeY];`? Do you mean `int MapSizeVector[sizeX][sizeY];`?

Comment: I already initialized it in Map.h

Comment: This line `MapSizeVector[sizeX][sizeY];` accesses the `vector<int>` at `sizeX` position and then the `int` element of this vector at `sizeY` position. If you want to change the size of a vector, use `resize` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should look like this:

```
void Map::SetMapSize(int sizeX, int sizeY, const char *filename)
{
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    out << "[Map]" << std::endl;
    MapSizeVector.resize(sizeX);

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
    {
        MapSizeVector[i].resize(sizeY);
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
        {
            char str[20];
            sprintf(str, "%d ", MapSizeVector[i][j]);
            out << str;
        }
        out << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1816388 those for loop conditions did (before edit) overrun by 1, wrong comparison operator...

Comment: @miloszmaki Your code is missing newlines, which are in example output of question.